# Skip NDK files while building or build library only once Android Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk, android-build

Gradle takes too long to build Native files (around 5 hrs) on Android. Please let me know if there are any attributes that would reduce the build time. Similarly, when I'm making changes in Java or Resources, The whole project is being built(including the C Files) which is increasing the testing time heavily. Is there a way where I build the C Files only once and skip it for the rest of the builds unless I particularly mention that they need to be included in the build.

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.application"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 5
        versionName "0.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0"
}
```

Comment: you can move native file to another project and use it as a module (for example as .aar file)

Comment: You C++ code should only be rebuilding if it has changed. If you see otherwise you should file a bug.